Confused about particular vector multiplication/scalar exercise
I'm currently working through this document to get a better understanding of algebra: https://www.justinmath.com/files/justinmath-linearAlgebra.pdf
So far, everything seems fairly straightforward, but the exercise 17) in chapter 1 (page 19) completely stumped me:
$$3( x + \langle 1, -1, 1, -1\rangle) = 2x$$
I would expect the result to be:
$$ 3( x + \langle1, -1, 1, -1\rangle) = 2x$$$$
      3x + 3\langle1, -1, 1, -1\rangle = 2x$$$$
                         x = -3\langle1, -1, 1, -1\rangle$$$$
                         x = \langle-3, 3, -3, 3\rangle$$
But according to the document, the result is:
$$x = \langle -1, 1, -1, 1\rangle$$
And now I'm completely lost and can't quite find an explanation as of why. Playing around with WolframAlpha confirms this, but trying other vectors, it seems all multiplications just return the original vector?
Example, $2\times \langle2, 4\rangle = \langle2, 4\rangle$ ( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+*+%28+vector+%7B+2%2C+4+%7D+%29 )
The reason I'm so confused by this, is that the document gives me different examples on page 4, "Scalars":
$$2 \times \langle2, 4\rangle = \langle2 \cdot (2), 2 \cdot (4)\rangle
               = \langle4, 8\rangle$$
The example in the book doesn't get simplified down to $\langle2, 4\rangle$.
What am I missing here? Why is $3( x + \langle1, -1, 1, -1\rangle) = 2x$ equivalent to $x = \langle-1, 1, -1, 1\rangle$ instead of $\langle-3, 3, -3, 3\rangle$? Can vectors just be simplified down like fractions? Wouldn't that remove an important information in that example equation?


The WolframAlpha did not take your input to be 2.<2, 4>, it couldn't understand the multiplied by 2 part apparently, as is evident in the statement "Using closest Wolfram|Alpha interpretation: vector { 2, 4 }". The result indeed should be <4, 8>.


You are right. The author changed his mind from $3x+a=2x$ to $3(x+a)=2x$ in between writing the problem statement and the answer key. That happens. Let them know.

@MichalAdamaszek I'm not quite sure that happened, OP seems to be missing somethings here

@insipidintegrator The OP is completely right about their solution, you are completely right about the Wolfram Alpha interpretation.

@MichalAdamaszek ah I missed some brackets. Apologies
